# Http Date to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string taken from an http response header field "Date" in this format:

```
"Sun, 24 Jun 2012 16:34:51 GMT"
```

what i want is to convert this string in a NSDate object. For this scope I have instantiated an `NSDateFormatter` using various format:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE',' dd' 'MMM' 'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss zzz"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE',' dd' 'MMM' 'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'"];
```

but when I print the string from date using:

```
[dateFormatter dateFromString:date]
```

I receive:

```
(null)
```

where am I doing wrong?

Comment: The result is still (null). I believe that the error is in the format of the month "MMM". I tried to format "24 Jun 2012" with the format "dd MMM yyyy" and the result is the same (null).

Comment: ok this one i tested and it works: [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE',' dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"]; if you still getting no result, than something else is wrong

Answer (score 9):

Not sure I understand the problem, as your own code seems to work fine for me:

```
NSString *dateStr = @"Sun, 24 Jun 2012 16:34:51 GMT";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE',' dd' 'MMM' 'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss zzz"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];

NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);
```

Which gives this output:

> Date: 2012-06-24 16:34:51 +0000

Unless I have misunderstood your question, this is the correct result.

Comment: The problem was that it lacked quaste two lines of code: 
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc]  initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];

Comment: This answer doesnt work for me, it shows me nil value for date

Comment: @booker If you're in the other country other than US, you should set the local of `NSDateFormatter` to en_US.

Comment: "en_US_POSIX" might be even better.